# Xamarin - How to know what has been clicked in collection view?

Tags: xamarin, button, collectionview

I have a `CollectionView` with an image and a button in it. I use following code to see if somebody pressed anywhere within the cell:

```
private void CollectionView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (((CollectionView)sender).SelectedItem != null)
    {
        var item = (picdata)e.CurrentSelection.FirstOrDefault();
        ((CollectionView)sender).SelectedItem = null;
        if (allowfullscreen == "1" || allowfullscreen == "true")
        { 
            Navigation.PushAsync(new Picture());
        }             
    }
}
```

But how can I know if he clicked the button inside the cell? I was trying to do it via the Click event, but then I do not know which one of all the buttons has been clicked.

Comment: you can use the BindingContext of the sender to determine which item the button click originated from

Comment: Question not clear. What are you trying to achieve.Post your XAML

Comment: @Jason, thank you, it worked.. If youpost it as answer I can accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the item from the BindingContext of the sender

```
var item = (picdata)(Button)sender.BindingContext;
```